# Panel increases in width contrary to intended code

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm constructing a panel that has a designated area where a user can drag their mouse cursor to resize the panel to be smaller or larger. Whenever the slider is engaged, instead of moving as expected, the panel jumps in size before being able to be moved.

When inspecting the element, I'm seeing contradictory information that I'm not fully understanding. The computed width is something much larger than what I'm setting from `element.style.width.` When I investigate where that width is coming from, the dev tools then shows the width that's coming from my style change. It almost seems as if a width value is getting recycled, but even when I update variables, the result is the same.

[image: Computed with of div]

[image: Width from element.style]

Again, I'm having trouble figuring out exactly why the code is performing like this. Any help with clarifying this issue would be much appreciated.

Here is a link to my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/great-platform-xkxhy2?file=/src/index.mjs

Comment: where is your element defined? the css is assigning 'width' to OBJECT of 'element.style', where, I'm sure you want to set, maybe element? depending on the interface, you need to use different sub objects

Comment: I have div encapsulating both panels, and panel 1 contains a div that is acting as the slider element. Panel 1 is being retrieved through `querySelector` and is assigned to the variable `leftPane.` When I update the size, it's through `leftPane.style.width.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flex items will grow/shrink to fit the available space. This is messing with your sizing. Add `flex-grow: 0;` so that your first panel will not size itself.

```
.panel-1 {
  background: darkorchid;
  min-width: 50px;
  position: relative;
  flex-grow:0;
  width:50%;
}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/competent-gates-tk4w6f?file=/src/styles.css

Comment: That was it! Thanks for helping me track down the source of the issue.